# Issue with getting data from an array of objects - vue.js / API / axios / proxy

Tags: api, vue.js, proxy, nested-object

First of all I'm using Vue.js to access data of an API using axios and a proxy
I'm trying to access the property of an object nested in the last array of several other arrays but I'm kinda hitting a wall, here's the detail :

[Global details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnb3m.png)

[the property I'm trying to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDO0h.png)

I've tried different ways but here's my latest try :

```
axios
    .get(proxyurl + history_url, { 
        reqHeaders
    })
    .then((reponse) => {
        console.log(reponse.data)
        this.lastItem = reponse.data.data.history[history.length-1]
        console.log(this.lastItem)
        this.lastEvol = this.lastItem.price
        console.log(this.lastEvol)
    })
```

The issue here is that the answer to "console.log(this.lastItem)" is :

[lastItem answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxRvJ.png)

The value of the properties are now different and incorrect.
Since it's showing "Proxy" as the root object name I thought that may be the issue but I'm not sure.

I've tried several other ways to access this property but only had errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`history` is undefined in the `history.length` expression.  Try this:

```js
.then((reponse) => {
    const history = reponse.data.data.history;
    console.log(reponse.data)
    this.lastItem = history[history.length-1]
    console.log(this.lastItem)
    this.lastEvol = this.lastItem.price
    console.log(this.lastEvol)
})
```